# Magento - SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL

Tags: soap, magento, soapclient

estou com este erro e infelizmente não consigo resolver o mesmo.

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://magento.cordeirosilva.adv.br/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1'

Meu codigo.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magento.cordeirosilva.adv.br/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
```

$sessionId = $proxy->login('xxxx', 'xxxxx');
$result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
var_dump($result);

O que estou fazendo de errado.